# Access the third party child component from parent component vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form component called `example-component` in which inside I have another third party child component for media upload called `media-uploader` like this

```
<example-component>
    <form :action= "something">
     // Some other input types 


     // This is a third party component I installed on my application so I dont have access to 
     its .js file
     <media-upload
        :ref="'cover_uploader'"
        :collection="'cover'"
        :url="'{{ route('admin.upload.media', $folder) }}'"
        :accepted-file-types="''"
        :max-number-of-files="5"
        :max-file-size-in-mb="100"
        :accepted-file-types="''">
     </media-upload>
    </form>
</example-component>
```

and the route inside the `:url` of the `media-uploader` leads to this logic in a controller

```
public function something()
{
   $variable = "Something";
   return response()->json($variable);
}
```

I have full access to the `example-component` but I don't have access to the `media-uploader`
So How can I get the `$variable` value in my `example-component` so that I can use that `$variable` in my `example-component`

Comment: It's not clear what _"the `$variable` value in my `example-component`"_ is. Where is this _`$variable`_ value defined? What does it have to do with your Laravel controller?

Comment: It depends on what the media-upload component is doing with the response object. Do you have a link to the component online?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a request with Axios or other tools to the server. 
in created() hook of the component.

I used [Axios](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios#readme) for this example

```
<example-component route="{{ route('admin.upload.media', $folder) }}">
...
</example-component>
```

and in your component .vue file, you can add

```
export default {
  props: {
    route: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      variable: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.axios(this.route).then(res => { this.variable = res.data });
  }
  ...
};
```